# MySQL Replace() unable to replace EXACT MATCH

Tags: mysql, replace, exact-match

Here's the issue. My query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = replace(`column`,'123','456');
```

Is not going to work. Here's why:

The numeric string '4123' now becomes '4456'.

What I would like is for only EXACT matches (column value equals exactly '123') to be replaced. Is this not possible with a simple UPDATE SET = REPLACE() query??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you shouldn't need `REPLACE` to do this:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourColumn = '456' WHERE yourColumn = '123';
```

Comment: And a +1 to you for being the basis of my answer :p

Comment: As usual, I was seeking an overly-complex solution to a simple task. Thank you!

Comment: @FurryWombat Hey, that's my bit :p

Comment: Hahaha, beat you to the punch. Gotta start working on that... life would be so much easier.

Answer (score 4):

As Paul says, you shouldn't need a `REPLACE()` call, just add a suitable `WHERE` clause.

That said, if this is part of a bigger query updating other columns too, try this:
`` SET `column`=IF(`column`=123, 456, `column`) ``

This will only give that column a new value if it meets the condition.

Comment: +1 Good point about other columns possibly needing to be updated.

Comment: Duly noted! For this situation, I will not need this, but will definitely keep in mind for future reference.